# Sort Days of the Week in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

I have an Access database I am querying with SQL from VB .NET. The Table I'm querying has a column called "Day" which has the days stored as the text data type in Access. I need to select all the unique instances in the field so am currently using:

```
SELECT Day FROM Slot GROUP BY Day
```

But this returns the days in alphabetical order when I need them in chronological order. Now assuming that the only possible values it can take are "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" ,"Thursday" and "Friday", what would you recommend doing to sort them correctly?

**Edit:** The table is called Slot and has three columns; SlotNumber (AutoNumber), Day (Text), SlotTime (Text). An example might be:

*SlotNumber:* 6

*Day:* Monday

*SlotTime:* 2:40PM

Comment: could you show atleast some records that are stored in `Day` table?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an answer button at the bottom of this page?

Comment: I do have an answer button, but I can't answer my own question within 8 hours. Not enough reputation.

Comment: I guess there's that. You should fix it (by editing the answer out of the question and adding it as an answer) when you get a chance. Glad you found something that worked for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are stuck with the data as is, I would recommend that you add an ORDER BY clause.  Within the ORDER BY clause you will want to map each distinct value to a numeric value.

e.g., Using IIf

```
SELECT Slot.Day
FROM Slot
GROUP BY Slot.Day
ORDER BY IIf(Slot.Day = "Monday", 1,
         IIf(Slot.Day = "Tuesday", 2,
         IIf(Slot.Day = "Wednesday", 3,
         IIf(Slot.Day = "Thursday", 4,
         IIf(Slot.Day = "Friday", 5)))));
```

e.g., Using SWITCH

```
SELECT Slot.Day
FROM Slot
GROUP BY Slot.Day
ORDER BY SWITCH(Slot.Day = 'Monday', 1,
                Slot.Day = 'Tuesday', 2,
                Slot.Day = 'Wednesday', 3,
                Slot.Day = 'Thursday', 4,
                Slot.Day = 'Friday', 5);
```

Comment: @todda.speot.is Thank you for pointing out an important detail that I clearly missed.  I have updated the answer to use the IIf syntax instead of the CASE.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "sort" them in the way you want. Why are you using the text values, anyway? The standard way to do this is to use numeric values to represent the days; 0=Sunday, 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, etc. So you would have an `int` field with values 1-5. Then you could sort it properly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was using it as a text field because I use the field as the text attribute of a label in VB .NET. Oh well I suppose I can convert it to a numerical field and look up the day in a new table. Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need a table to look up the values. In fact, I think there's an enum you could use. (or you could easily create one)

Comment: @todda.speot.is Oop. totally missed that this was Access; right, Steven's answer won't work.